# Sitecore FieldRenderer to return relative path

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7

I am using following line of code to render image:

```cs
string html = Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer.Render(
                                            Item,
                                            this.Field,
                                            renderParameters + "&disable-web-editing=" + this.DisableWebEditing.ToString());
```

Following string is assigned in html:

```xml
<img src="http://localhost/~/assets/images/widgets/contact.png?bc=White&amp;h=130&amp;la=en&amp;w=130" width="130" height="130" />
```

Is there any way so that `src` of image is relative path?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your application doesn't have any customizations, `FieldRenderer` uses `MediaUrlOptions` to know how to generate the url.

`MediaUrlOptions` uses `Settings.Media.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl` to determine whether the full server url should be included or not.

Check your setting in the configuration and set it to proper value:

```xml
<!--  MEDIA ALWAYS INCLUDE SERVER URL
        If true, Sitecore will generate absolute URLs when it uses the MediaProvider API and/or the link provider to render media URLs.
        If blank, Sitecore will use the same value as the alwaysIncludeServerUrl attribute from the link provider.
        Default value: "" (use the value from the link provider)
  -->
<setting name="Media.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl" value="" />
```